# Insert zero value rows for missing column value Postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, psql

I have this table (elev_table) :

```
 country      | cat |    elev
--------------+-----+----------
 USA          |   0 |    41.46
 USA          |   1 |   878.90
 USA          |   2 |    78.01    
 CAN          |   0 |    46.00
 CAN          |   1 |    78.92
 CAN          |   2 |    78.01
 CAN          |   4 |   667.77
 CAN          |   5 |    10.80
```

How can I create a query to return the same table, filled with missing cat values? The cat column has to values from (-1 to 5) but not every country value contains every cat value.

Essentially, for every country in my table I need rows with elevation values for every cat value of -1 to 5.....

For example I want the resulting table to look like:

```
 country      | cat |    elev
--------------+-----+----------
 USA          |  -1 |        0
 USA          |   0 |    41.46
 USA          |   1 |   878.90
 USA          |   2 |    78.01
 USA          |   3 |        0
 USA          |   4 |        0
 USA          |   5 |        0  
 CAN          |  -1 |        0 
 CAN          |   0 |    46.00
 CAN          |   1 |    78.92
 CAN          |   2 |    78.01
 CAN          |   3 |        0
 CAN          |   4 |   667.77
 CAN          |   5 |    10.80
```

I believe 0 would be a good representation, but maybe NULL would be better?

I have tried the following query, but this doesn't create missing row values for each country... I know I am missing something but can't seem to figure out what!!!

```
with cat_series as(
  select generate_series(-1,5) as fullcat
)

select fullcat, coalesce(sum(t.elev),0), t.country
from cat_series
  left join elev_table t on cat_series.fullcat=t.cat
group by fullcat, t.country
order by fullcat, t.country;
```

Still quite new to postgres, sql. Any help or pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `cross join` followed by a `left join`:

```
select c.country, g.cat, coalesce(sum(t.elev), 0)
from (select distinct country from elev_table) c cross join
     generate_series(-1, 5) as g(cat) left join
     elev_table et
     on et.country = c.country and et.cat = g.cat
group by c.country, g.cat;
```

I left the `group by` in the query, although based on the sample data, this is sufficient:

```
select c.country, g.cat, coalesce(t.elev, 0)
from (select distinct country from elev_table) c cross join
     generate_series(-1, 5) as g(cat) left join
     elev_table et
     on et.country = c.country and et.cat = g.cat;
```

You can remove the `coalesce()` if you prefer `NULL` to `0`.

Comment: Lets say there is an additional column in the elev_table. Wouldn't any where statements cause the missing rows not to be filled? 
for example: in the below table WHERE et.color is not null) 

    country      | cat |    elev   | color
    --------------+-----+-----------+-------
     USA          |   0 |    41.46  | blue
     USA          |   2 |    78.01  |   
     CAN          |   0 |    46.00  | blue
     CAN          |   1 |    78.92  | red
     CAN          |   2 |    78.01  |
     CAN          |   4 |   667.77 | blue
     CAN          |   5 |    10.80  |

Comment: @F.Ronald . . . A `WHERE` clause would affect the results.  If you have another question, perhaps you should ask it as a question.